# why LibreOffice creates inverse question mark in equation when odt file imported from word doc or docx

Tags: libreoffice, odt, libreoffice-basic

I have equation in .docx file is

[image]

when I save word file to .odt this equation becomes

[image]

how can avoid this inverse question mark?

Answer (score 6):

The solution: Edit the equation and type double quotes ("") after equality sign.

Comment: thnx epaminondas but is there any setting provided by libre for avoid this

Answer (score 2):

To summarize: You have an equation in a DOCX file created by something. If this something is MS Word, then the file itself is probably correct and there is a bug in LO. Please test your document against the latest version of LO and if it still fails, file a bug report. Baring that, send me a simple document that demonstrates the problem and I will happily file the bug report for you after verifying that the problem still exists in the latest version of LO (they recently made some fixes to this part of LO).